# How do I install Falkon browser in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, cmake

I have downloaded the source code of Falkon from GitHub repository, but when I try to generate a make using the CMakeLists.txt it throws up some error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QuickWidgets"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5QuickWidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5quickwidgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5QuickWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "Qt5QuickWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "Qt5QuickWidgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:46 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What should I do to complete the installation?

Comment: Qt5QuickWidgets : `apt-file search libQt5QuickWidgets.so` ... `sudo apt install qtdeclarative5-dev` → Provides `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5QuickWidgets.so`

Answer (score 1):

Falkon is a new and very fast QtWebKit browser. It aims to be a lightweight   web browser available through all major platforms. This project has been  originally started only for educational purposes, but from its start Falkon has grown into a feature-rich browser. Falkon has AdBlock built-in and enabled by default. Falkon also can import bookmarks from Firefox, Chrome, Opera and .html file(s).

To install the native Falkon browser snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install falkon --channel candidate
```

The candidate version of the Falkon browser snap package is currently 3.0.1, the same as the current version at https://www.falkon.org/.

To launch Falkon from the terminal:

```
snap run falkon
```

The falkon snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.

Support for playing Flash videos in Falkon can be added with the following commands:

```
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin 
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash # 16.04 and later
```

Comment: This explains how OP can install the browser, but the question is about building. I need some help building it as well as I have customised some code.

Answer (score -1):

I have had better experience with kde programs running on Lubuntu 18.04. Apper instead of Synaptic, for example.                                         sudo snap install kde-frameworks-5

Let this finish installing, then:

```
sudo snap install falkon --edge
```