# Falcon browser startup problem

Tags: software-installation

Comment oct 8 2019:
**Falkon browser up running after reinstalling Ubuntu**. :-)
It's a System 76 Meerkat desktop. A week ago I tried to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, but it could'nt find the GPU. Instead I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, which found the GPU, then I updated to 18.04.3 LTS before installing any software/apps. **Everything is perfect now**.
end of comment

My original question of sept 2019:

Falkon has worked perfectly since installed about 6 month ago, but after a reboot it would not launch.
Several times I have tried uninstall, reboot, and then reinstall, but without success.

Always installed via "Ubuntu software", which then shows Falkon is installed - but pressing the button "Launch", nothing happens.The desktop shortcut is same.

A right-click on the icon says: `"No Application found"`

As a Linux newbee I have no idea where to look for the error.

As a test I installed "Stellarium", and it runs perfectly.

My very first question here, I apologize if doing anything wrong.

OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`

From terminal:

```
~$ snap run falkon
```

/snap/falkon/60/kf5-launch: line 209: /snap/falkon/60/kf5-locale-gen: No such file or directory

nano /snap/falkon/60/kf5-launch

Here only the lower part of the: GNU nano 2.9.3   `/snap/falkon/60/kf5-launch`  [Paths]
Data = $KF5/usr/share/qt5/
Translations = $KF5/usr/share/qt5/translations
EOF

'# requires `locales, libc-bin` being stage-packages
if [ -e $KF5/usr/share/i18n ]; then
export I18NPATH=$KF5/usr/share/i18n
locpath=$XDG_DATA_HOME/locale

mkdir -p $locpath
export LOCPATH=$locpath:/usr/lib/locale # core snap contains C.UTF-8 already

LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 $SNAP/kf5-locale-gen || exit 1      # <<< This is line 209
fi
exec "$@"

Since the error message points at the kf5-locale-gen, I perhaps should aim focus at "locale-gen"?
There are no error messages when updating or running other applications, only Falkon will not start.
I see there are two folders in the Falkon folder, "60" and "current", which both contain this:
command-falkon.wrapper  kf5  kf5-launch  kf5-portal-launch  meta  snap  usr

gn@Kat:/snap$ dir
bin
gnome-3-26-1604
gnome-logs
kde-frameworks-5-core18
core
gnome-3-28-1804
gnome-system-monitor
okteta
core18
gnome-calculator
gtk-common-themes
README
falkon
gnome-characters
kde-frameworks-5
stellarium-plars

gn@Kat:/snap/falkon$ dir
60
current

gn@Kat:/snap/falkon/current$ dir
command-falkon.wrapper  kf5  kf5-launch  kf5-portal-launch  meta  snap  usr

gn@Kat:/snap/falkon/60$ dir
command-falkon.wrapper  kf5  kf5-launch  kf5-portal-launch  meta  snap  usr

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing the package directly? this may help https://askubuntu.com/a/1110158/418984

Comment: SamFlynn, thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I get the same error. A Falcon icon on the desktop, but no response, and right-click gives the message: "No Application found".
The only difference is that Falkon does not appear as installed in "Ubuntu Software". 

gn@Kat:~$ sudo snap install falkon --channel candidate
[sudo] password for gn: 
falkon (candidate) 3.1.0 from KDE✓ installed
gn@Kat:~$ snap run falkon 
/snap/falkon/60/kf5-launch: line 209: /snap/falkon/60/kf5-locale-gen: No such file or directory
gn@Kat:~$

Comment: After reboot Falkon appears in the "Ubuntu Software", but Still same problem.

Comment: My Falkon browser which worked up to now gave the same error message. There is a bug with the falkon snap package.

Comment: Karel, thank you very much, I didn't know. Nothing we can repair but have to wait for a new version Falkon?

Comment: Every time this happened with a snap I always did the same thing. I didn't uninstall the snap package, and waited for a subsequent update to fix the problem.

Comment: Once again I have tried installing Falkon, but still the same problem. (Snap-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Falkon 3.1 not starting. Try Falkon 3.0 from the software library. Both 3.1 and 3.0 can be found in the software library.  It works for me with Xubuntu 18.04. Hope this helps. Cheers Neil

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you. It is a known bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=411453

Comment: Thank you all. :-)  My very first question here - do I have to finish or close the question? Now a month ago I re-installed a working version - and yes, it's version 3.0 :-)